# \csuse inside a \NewEnviron using the environment parameter

Tags: environments, etoolbox

I am trying define a environment that displays a text specified by the parameter of the environment. The following example demonstrates it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\csdef{bla1}{Bla1Text}
\csdef{bla2}{Bla2Text}
\NewEnviron{myenv}[1][]{%
    env: #1 
    \csuse{bla#1} % does not work
    \BODY
}
\begin{document}
    \csuse{bla1}\\ % works as expected
    \begin{myenv}{1} body1 \end{myenv} \\
    \begin{myenv}{2} body2 \end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Is `\NewEnviron` incompatible with the `etoolbox` package or is there a possibility to fix my code above?

Note: In a regular environment `\csuse` works without problems but I want to change the behavior of the environment so that it hides the content if the `\csuse` variable is defined or not and this can AFAIK only be done using `\NewEnviron`. And changing `\csuse` is not an option as it is already used widely in my real document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're using specifies that the argument to the `myenv` environment is optional, with empty default value.

So with your definition,

```
\begin{myenv}
body
\end{myenv}
```

will execute `\csuse{bla}`, while

```
\begin{myenv}[1]
body
\end{myenv}
```

will execute `\csuse{bla1}`. If you want a mandatory argument in braces, which seems the case by looking at your example, the code should be

```
\NewEnviron{myenv}[1]{%
    env: #1 
    \csuse{bla#1} % does not work
    \BODY
}
```

and in this case

```
\begin{myenv}{2}
body
\end{myenv}
```

will execute `\csuse{bla2}`.